# Создать файл/папку во внутренней памяти(internal storage)

Tags: java, android, android-file

Я пытаюсь создать файл:

```
File path=new File(getFileDir(),"MyFolder");
OutputStreamWriter out;
try
{
 File f=new File(path,"my.txt");
 out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(f.getPath,MODE_PRIVATE));
 out.write("test");
 out.close();
}catch(IOException e)
 { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Не получается. Пожалуйста, объясните где ошибка и как это делать правильно.

Comment: А что не работает? Если именно этот код используете, то он у вас просто не компилится из-за опечаток.

Comment: этот код у меня в onClick (для теста). При нажатии на кнопку происходит вылет приложения

Comment: @MichaelEn, экстрасенсы все тутошние в отпуске. А без них нам не узнать на какой строке и какая ошибка возникает. Мы же не видим, что у вас в `logCat` пишется...

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы не помянули манифест в вопросе, значит ваша ошибка в том, что вы не добавили нужные разрешения в него.

Добавить надо это разрешение внутрь основного тега манифеста:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: В вопросе речь о внутренней памяти, тут права все по-умолчанию есть.

Comment: эта строка в манифесте прописана

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что поздно. Но вы не создали файл, перед открытием потока файла.

```
File f=new File(path,"my.txt");
f.createNewFile();
...
```

Comment: Это и не нужно - `FileOutputStream` сам создаёт файл, если он не существует и у приложения есть полномочия создать этот файл. Проблема вопроса в том, что  метод `openFileOutput()` принимает только имя файла без путей, а автор передал ему полный путь к файлу.